# ROR - Active record avoid n+1 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

I have a model (News) associated with another model (Category), so in News model i have:

```
has_and_belong_to_many :news_categories, join:table: 'news_categories_news'
```

I want to take all news with own categories, so:

```
News.find(/*conditions*/).includes(:news_categories)
```

If I check in console I see the right inner join query, but when I call

```
@news.news_categories
```

(Where news is a single news in the result array) if I check in console I see another query to take the categories for the current news, how can I avoid this redundant query?

p.s: sorry for my english...

Comment: Try `News.includes(:news_categories).find(/*conditions*/)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `.includes` can't work when chained after `.find`. Reason - `find` will *not return* the `ActiveRecord::Relation` which is necessary for relational chaining; it will rather return the matching `News` object or error.

You should do:

```
@all_news = News.includes(:news_categories).where(id: 1)
@news = @all_news.first
@news.news_categories # shouldn't invoke new query
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all but i resolved with `eager_load()`
It's generate just once query!